# Church Fathers exegesis of the Rock of Matthew 16:18?

Tags: catholicism, exegesis, early-church, church-fathers

How do Catholics answer this [Patristic Exegesis of the Rock of Matthew 16:18](https://christiantruth.com/articles/articles-roman-catholicism/fathersmt16/#easy-footnote-36-1884) compiled by William Webster?  As a Catholic I am a bit confused.

**Augustine**

Remember, in this man Peter, the rock. He’s the one, you see, who on being questioned by the Lord about who the disciples said he was, replied, ‘You are the Christ, the Son of the living God.’ On hearing this, Jesus said to him, ‘Blessed are you, Simon Bar Jona, because flesh and blood did not reveal it to you, but my Father who is in heaven. And I tell you’…’You are Peter, Rocky, and on this rock I shall build my Church, and the gates of the underworld will not conquer her. To you shall I give the keys of the kingdom. Whatever you bind on earth shall also be bound in heaven; whatever you loose on earth shall also be loosed in heaven’ (Mt 16:15-19). In Peter, Rocky, we see our attention drawn to the rock. Now the apostle Paul says about the former people, ‘They drank from the spiritual rock that was following them; but the rock was Christ’ (1 Cor 10:4). So this disciple is called Rocky from the rock, like Christian from Christ.
Why have I wanted to make this little introduction? In order to suggest to you that in Peter the Church is to be recognized. Christ, you see, *built his Church not on a man but on Peter’s confession*. What is Peter’s confession? ‘You are the Christ, the Son of the living God.’ There’s the rock for you, there’s the foundation, there’s where the Church has been built, which the gates of the underworld cannot conquer.
<sub>John Rotelle, O.S.A., Ed., *The Works of Saint Augustine* (New Rochelle: New City Press, 1993), *Sermons*, Volume III/6, *Sermon* 229P.1, p. 327.</sub>

**Ambrose**

He, then, who before was silent, to teach us that we ought not to repeat the words of the impious, this one, I say, when he heard: ‘But who do you say I am,’ immediately, not unmindful of his station, exercised his primacy, that is, the primacy of confession, not of honor; the primacy of belief, not of rank…This, then, is Peter who has replied for the rest of the Apostles; rather, before the rest of men. And so he is called the foundation, because he knows how to preserve not only his own but the common foundation. Christ agreed with him; the Father revealed it to him. For he who speaks of the true generation of the Father, received it from the Father, did not receive it from the flesh. Faith, then, is the foundation of the Church, for it was not said of Peter’s flesh, but of his faith, that ‘the gates of hell shall not prevail against it.’ But his confession of faith conquered hell. And this confession did not shut out one heresy, for, since the Church like a good ship is often buffeted by many waves, the foundation of the Church should prevail against all heresies. The day will fail me sooner than the names of heretics and the different sects, yet against all is this general faith-that Christ is the Son of God, and eternal from the Father, and born of the Virgin Mary.
<sub>*The Fathers of the Church* (Washington D.C.: Catholic University, 1963), Saint Ambrose, *The Sacrament of the Incarnation of Our Lord* 4.32-5.35, pp. 230-1.</sub>

**Athanasius**

I know moreover that not only this thing saddens you, but also the fact that while others have obtained the churches by violence, you are meanwhile cast out from your places. For they hold the places, but you the Apostolic Faith. They are, it is true, in the places, but outside of the true Faith; while you are outside the places indeed, but the Faith, within you…But ye are blessed, who by faith are in the Church, dwell upon the foundations of the faith, and have full satisfaction, even the highest degree of faith which remains among you unshaken. For it has come down to you from Apostolic tradition, and frequently has accursed envy wished to unsettle it, but has not been able. On the contrary, they have rather been cut off from their attempts to do so. For thus it is written, ‘Thou art the Son of the Living God,’ Peter confessing it by revelation of the Father, and being told, ‘Blessed art thou Simon Barjona, for flesh and blood did not reveal it to thee, but My Father Who is in heaven,’ and the rest. No one therefore will ever prevail against your Faith, most beloved brethren.
<sub>Philip Schaff, *Nicene and Post Nicene Fathers* (Grand Rapids: Eerdmans, 1953), Volume IV, St. Athanasius, *Letters of Athanasius*, Letter 29, p. 551.</sub>

**More exegesis can be read in [here](https://christiantruth.com/articles/articles-roman-catholicism/fathersmt16/#easy-footnote-36-1884)**

Comment: You should edit the question to include what exactly you'd like an answer to. Link is nice as a reference but please include the full question here (links can break, pages removed, etc)

Comment: @WenuraRavindu I improved your post.  I can guess what you're asking (how come the interpretation of the Rock doesn't point to the bishop of Rome), but you have to be the one making it explicit in the post.

Comment: Thanks. Wonderful edit

Comment: The phrasing "How do Catholics answer this..." makes it sound like it is something *contradictory*, or attempting to be such, to the Catholic Faith. I don't see what there is for us to answer.

Comment: @SupportiveDante I am not very fluent in English if something like offensive or non-appropriate I didn't mean that sorry for that my bad.

Comment: No, not at all. I just don't understand the question. As @GratefulDisciple pointed out, it's hard to tell what you find difficult about the article. What do you, as a Catholic, find concerning about it?

Comment: @SupportiveDante Who is the Rock in Matter 16:18?

Comment: Simon who was called Peter

Comment: @SupportiveDante, I think the confusion is this statement: "*Christ, you see, built his Church not on a man but on Peter’s confession. What is Peter’s confession? ‘You are the Christ, the Son of the living God.’ There’s the rock for you, there’s the foundation*".  I.e. the "rock" upon which the Church is built isn't Peter himself, but upon the truth of what Peter said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Church Fathers exegesis of the Rock of [**Matthew 16:18**](https://www.newadvent.org/bible/mat016.htm#vrs17)?

> 17 And Jesus answered him, Blessed art thou, Simon son of Jona; it is not flesh and blood, it is my Father in heaven that has revealed this to thee. 18 And I tell thee this in my turn, that thou art Peter, and it is upon this rock that I will build my church; and the gates of hell shall not prevail against it; 19 and I will give to thee the keys of the kingdom of heaven; and whatever thou shalt bind on earth shall be bound in heaven; and whatever thou shalt loose on earth shall be loosed in heaven.
>
> 17 Respondens autem Jesus, dixit ei: Beatus es Simon Bar Jona: quia caro et sanguis non revelavit tibi, sed Pater meus, qui in cælis est. 18 Et ego dico tibi, quia tu es Petrus, et super hanc petram ædificabo Ecclesiam meam, et portæ inferi non prævalebunt adversus eam. 19 Et tibi dabo claves regni cælorum. Et quodcumque ligaveris super terram, erit ligatum et in cælis: et quodcumque solveris super terram, erit solutum et in cælis.
>
> 17 ἀποκριθεὶς δὲ ὁ Ἰησοῦς εἶπεν αὐτῷ: μακάριος εἶ, Σίμων Βαριωνᾶ, ὅτι σὰρξ καὶ αἷμα οὐκ ἀπεκάλυψέν σοι ἀλλ' ὁ πατήρ μου ὁ ἐν τοῖς οὐρανοῖς. 18 κἀγὼ δέ σοι λέγω ὅτι σὺ εἶ Πέτρος, καὶ ἐπὶ ταύτῃ τῇ **πέτρᾳ** οἰκοδομήσω μου τὴν ἐκκλησίαν, καὶ πύλαι ᾅδου οὐ κατισχύσουσιν αὐτῆς. 19 δώσω σοι τὰς κλεῖδας τῆς βασιλείας τῶν οὐρανῶν, καὶ ὃ ἐὰν δήσῃς ἐπὶ τῆς γῆς ἔσται δεδεμένον ἐν τοῖς οὐρανοῖς, καὶ ὃ ἐὰν λύσῃς ἐπὶ τῆς γῆς ἔσται λελυμένον ἐν τοῖς οὐρανοῖς.

The Church upholds what Jesus said to Peter:

> > Thou art Peter [Cepha, transliterated also Kipha] and upon this rock [Cepha] I will build my Church.
>
> The word for Peter and for rock in the original Aramaic is one and the same; this renders it evident that the various attempts to explain the term "rock" as having reference not to Peter himself but to something else are misinterpretations. It is Peter who is the rock of the Church. The term ecclesia (ekklesia) here employed is the Greek rendering of the Hebrew qahal, the name which denoted the Hebrew nation viewed as God's Church.
>
> **Objections**
>
> The meaning of this passage does not seem to have been challenged by any writer until the rise of the sixteenth-century heresies. Since then a great variety of interpretations have been put forward by Protestant controversialists. These agree in little save in the rejection of the plain sense of Christ's words. Some Anglican controversy tends to the view that the reward promised to St. Peter consisted in the prominent part taken by him in the initial activities of the Church, but that he was never more than primus inter pares among the Apostles. It is manifest that this is quite insufficient as an explanation of the terms of Christ's promise. - [The Pope](https://www.newadvent.org/cathen/12260a.htm)

As no serious objections to this text did not really arise until the 16th century, the text itself has not been hammered out by the Church Fathers.

I have heard claims that the Greek word for rock was a mistranslation and should have been pebble, as if saying to Peter has a correct to Jesus’ question and is a chip off the block! Totally untrue.

The Greek employs clear the word for rock (**πέτρα**) here and not a pebble or small stone (**πετραδάκι**).

> “‘But,’ you [Jovinian] will say, ‘it was on Peter that the Church was founded’ [Matt. 16:18]. Well . . . one among the twelve is chosen to be their head in order to remove any occasion for division” - (Against Jovinian 1:26 [A.D. 393]).

“I follow no leader but Christ and join in communion with none but your blessedness [Pope Damasus I], that is, with the chair of Peter. I know that this is the rock on which the Church has been built. Whoever eats the Lamb outside this house is profane. Anyone who is not in the ark of Noah will perish when the flood prevails” (Letters 15:2 [A.D. 396]).As for what the Church Fathers say about who Christ was referring to in this passage is clearly St. Peter, the Prince of the Apostles.

> [***Origins of Peter as Pope***](https://www.churchfathers.org/origins-of-peter-as-pope)
>
> **Tatian the Syrian**
>
> > “Simon Cephas answered and said, ‘You are the Messiah, the Son of the living God.’ Jesus answered and said unto him, ‘Blessed are you, Simon, son of Jonah: flesh and blood has not revealed it unto thee, but my Father which is in heaven. And I say unto thee also, that you are Cephas, and on this rock will I build my Church; and the gates of hades shall not prevail against it” (The Diatesseron 23 [A.D. 170]).
>
> **Tertullian**
>
> > “Was anything withheld from the knowledge of Peter, who is called ‘the rock on which the Church would be built’ [Matt. 16:18] with the power of ‘loosing and binding in heaven and on earth’ [Matt. 16:19]?” (Demurrer Against the Heretics 22 [A.D. 200]).
>
> “[T]he Lord said to Peter, ‘On this rock I will build my Church, I have given you the keys of the kingdom of heaven [and] whatever you shall have bound or loosed on earth will be bound or loosed in heaven’ [Matt. 16:18–19]. . . . What kind of man are you, subverting and changing what was the manifest intent of the Lord when he conferred this personally upon Peter? Upon you, he says, I will build my Church; and I will give to you the keys” (Modesty 21:9–10 [A.D. 220]).
>
> **Origen**
>
> > “Look at [Peter], the great foundation of the Church, that most solid of rocks, upon whom Christ built the Church [Matt. 16:18]. And what does our Lord say to him? ‘Oh you of little faith,’ he says, ‘why do you doubt?’ [Matt. 14:31]” (Homilies on Exodus 5:4 [A.D. 248]).
>
> **Optatus**
>
> > “You cannot deny that you are aware that in the city of Rome the episcopal chair was given first to Peter; the chair in which Peter sat, the same who was head—that is why he is also called Cephas [‘Rock’]—of all the apostles; the one chair in which unity is maintained by all” (The Schism of the Donatists 2:2 [A.D. 367]).
>
> **Ambrose of Milan**
>
> > “[Christ] made answer: ‘You are Peter, and upon this rock will I build my Church. . . . ’ Could he not, then, strengthen the faith of the man to whom, acting on his own authority, he gave the kingdom, whom he called the rock, thereby declaring him to be the foundation of the Church [Matt. 16:18]?” (The Faith 4:5 [A.D. 379]).
>
> > “It is to Peter that he says: ‘You are Peter, and upon this rock I will build my Church’ [Matt. 16:18]. Where Peter is, there is the Church. And where the Church is, no death is there, but life eternal” (Commentary on Twelve Psalms of David 40:30 [A.D. 389]).
>
> **Jerome**
>
> > “‘But,’ you [Jovinian] will say, ‘it was on Peter that the Church was founded’ [Matt. 16:18]. Well . . . one among the twelve is chosen to be their head in order to remove any occasion for division” (Against Jovinian 1:26 [A.D. 393]).
>
> > “I follow no leader but Christ and join in communion with none but your blessedness [Pope Damasus I], that is, with the chair of Peter. I know that this is the rock on which the Church has been built. Whoever eats the Lamb outside this house is profane. Anyone who is not in the ark of Noah will perish when the flood prevails” (Letters 15:2 [A.D. 396]).

The traditional texts the Church employs as proof that Christ constituted St. Peter head of His Church is found in the two famous Petrine texts, **Matthew 16:17-19**, and [**John 21:15-17**](https://www.newadvent.org/bible/joh021.htm#vrs15).

The Scriptural passage from the Gospel of St. John receives an admirable comment from St. Chrysostom:

> He saith to him, "Feed my sheep". Why does He pass over the others and speak of the sheep to Peter? He was the chosen one of the Apostles, the mouth of the disciples, the head of the choir. For this reason Paul went up to see him rather than the others. And also to show him that he must have confidence now that his denial had been purged away. He entrusts him with the rule [prostasia] over the brethren. . . . If anyone should say "Why then was it James who received the See of Jerusalem?", I should reply that He made Peter the teacher not of that see but of the whole world. [St. John Chrysostom, [Homily 88 on John, 21](https://www.newadvent.org/fathers/240188.htm). Cf. Origen, "In Ep. ad Rom.", 5:10; Ephraem Syrus "Hymn. in B. Petr." in "Bibl. Orient. Assemani", 1:95; Leo I, "Serm. iv de natal.", 2].

Comment: Regarding the link you provide to New Advent for John 21, would you know which Greek is being shown in the left-hand column? Thank you.

Comment: @I.Chekhov Koine Greek

Comment: Thank you kindly.